Как запустить в определенном порядке все функции в классе Python?
Есть написанный код на Python состоящий из класса и некоторого количества функций, нужно поочередно запустить все функции это класса, но как это сделать?
class Foo:
    def one(self):
        print("one")
    
    def two(self):
        print("two")
    
    ...


dir командой пройдись

__dict__ / __slots__ не спасёт?

import inspect
class Foo:
     # def __init__(self):
     #      pass
     def one(self):
          print("one")

     def two(self):
          print("two")

x=Foo()
methods = [member for member in inspect.getmembers(x, inspect.ismethod) if member[0] != '__init__']
for name, method in methods:
    method()




dost_members=inspect.getmembers(x, inspect.ismethod) #Все методы
print(dost_members)
for name,method in dost_members:
    method()


one
two
    [('one', <bound method Foo.one of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000001888ADABD00>>), ('two', <bound method Foo.two of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000001888ADABD00>>)]
one
two

